# Is there any simple format for visualising quad trees?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I have some data with presence/absence on big grid, internally represented as quad tree.

Are there any convenient formats for showing that to users?
Neither huge number of rectangles with svg nor huge number of pixels with png feel right.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make good looking quad trees in a [tree map](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap/).